# Is it possible to stop Xcode adding a breakpoint when I click on a line number?

Tags: xcode, user-interface

Whenever I click on a line number inside Xcode (I'm using v5 and v6 beta) it adds a breakpoint, like so:

I realise this is "intentional". I also see the advantage of having it to that. But you don't always want it to do this, and for the life of me, I can't seem to find a way to *disable* this behaviour. I know how to disable the specific breakpoint or delete it altogether, I just don't want that behaviour (i.e. creating a breakpoint) in the first place when I click on a line number.

You see, I mainly use Xcode on my Macbook Air. There isn't exactly a big amount of screen real estate and it is all too easy to accidentally add a breakpoint when I don't want to.

Does anyone know if it is possible to *stop* this behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

Goto Xcode menu -> Preferences -> Text Editing tab and untick "Line numbers" box, if you can live without line numbers in your code.

Currently, in my Xcode 14.3, a "breakpoint management" popup menu shows up when you right-click on a breakpoint line. But there is no action if right-click on a non-breakpoint line number. I wish Apple disabled left-click on a non-breakpoint all together and only use right-click to manage breakpoint in the editing source code screen area. i.e; right-click on a non-breakpoint line to turn its breakpoint on. Right-click again (on a breakpoint line) to popup its "breakpoint management" menu.